# bx-slider is not working properly with rails in heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, bxslider

I am facing an issue with bx-slider in my rails application after deploying it in heroku.slider is working properly in localhost but in heroku it is not showing controls icons and every time i click for next slide it goes to  the last slide.

My Page url is >>> `http://mayank-listenloop.herokuapp.com/presentations/1`

Please help me if any one have knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of the Rails asset pipeline in production is to append a hash to the end of each asset. This allows browsers to cache assets but be forced to download them when the assets change. Since your CSS directly references the image files, the production versions with the appended hash are not found.

There are two ways you can fix this. The first is to modify the CSS that comes with the slider. In the bxSlider CSS, find the lines that contain

```
url(/assets/bx_loader.gif)
```

and

```
url(/assets/controls.png)
```

Change `url` to `image-url`. Append `.scss` to the end of the CSS filename so the Sprockets preprocessor will convert the `image-url` into the correct filename with the caching hash appended.

Alternately, you could use the [bxslider-rails](https://github.com/manfe/bxslider-rails) gem, which has already been modified for use with Rails. (See for example [this use of `image-url`](https://github.com/manfe/bxslider-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bxslider.css.scss#L52) in the CSS.) To do that, just add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bxslider-rails'
```

And run `bundle install`.

The Rails-specific gem method seems preferable to me, because it’s likely the gem will be maintained, so you can get upgrades without having to repeat the CSS modification.